# text in commutative diagrams

Tags: tikz-cd

How can I replace letters with text or say a text box. Consider the following example. As you might notice in the output, the text is not quite okay. Is there a way to correct it please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,calc,shapes.misc,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{degil/.style={
                decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.5 with {
                \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
                %\draw[thick] (tempnode.north east) -- (tempnode.south west);
                }
                },
                postaction={decorate}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
    &  B \arrow[degil,shift left=1.5ex]{dr}{}  &  \\
  Stochastic Independence \arrow{ur}   &   & C \arrow [shift left=.5ex]{ul} \\
  & D \arrow{ur} & 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text{Stochastic Independence}` (with `\usepackage{amsmath}`), which is the standard way for adding normal text in math formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possibilities, using `mathtools` and `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,calc,shapes.misc,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{degil/.style={
                decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.5 with {
                \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
                %\draw[thick] (tempnode.north east) -- (tempnode.south west);
                }
                },
                postaction={decorate}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
    &  B \arrow[degil,shift left=1.5ex]{dr}{}  &  \\
\fbox{\Centerstack[l]{Stochastic\\Independence}}\arrow{ur}   &   & C \arrow [shift left=.5ex]{ul} \\
  & D \arrow{ur} &
\end{tikzcd}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
    &  B \arrow[degil,shift left=1.5ex]{dr}{}  &  \\
\Centerstack[l]{Stoch\rlap{astic}\\\rlap{Independence}}\arrow{ur}   &   & C \arrow [shift left=.5ex]{ul} \\
  & D \arrow{ur} &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks so much Bernard. While I see stuff related to rlap and centerstack etc in the manual, would it be possible for you to explain in very simple words what do these macros(?) do?

Comment: `\rlap` and `\llap` are plain TeX macros. Roughly explained from my code, typing `Stoch\rlap{astic}`inserts Stochastic, but the `astic` part has 0pt width, hence it is as though the inserted word were only `Stoc`, hence the point of application of the double arrow. `\llap` does the same, but in the opposite direction. `\Centerstack` (from the `stackengine` package) stacks lines of text and centres the result vertically with respect to the base line.

Comment: Wonderful, I'll try it out to make my diagram a bit more elegant! Thanks and cheers

Comment: Let me mention that these ‘lap commands’ work only in text mode, but the `mathtools` package (which should be loaded instead of `amsmath` which it loads anyway) defines a `\mathrlap` and a `\mathllap` commands, and adds a `\clap` and a `\mathclap` commands, the latter being very useful whan you have long summation indices. You should take a look at `Mathmode`  to learn how to fine tune math typing.

Comment: I see, thanks very much indeed Bernard! I am about to post another question for which I suspect this new thing that I have encountered  (thanks to your kind help) may be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for other packages, except perhaps `amsmath` that's recommended anyway when math is used in a document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,calc,shapes.misc,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{degil/.style={
                decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.5 with {
                \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
                %\draw[thick] (tempnode.north east) -- (tempnode.south west);
                }
                },
                postaction={decorate}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
    &  B \arrow[degil,shift left=1.5ex]{dr}{}  &  \\
  \text{Stochastic Independence} \arrow{ur}   &   & C \arrow [shift left=.5ex]{ul} \\
  & D \arrow{ur} & 
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
    &  B \arrow[degil,shift left=1.5ex]{dr}{}  &  \\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Stochastic\\ Independence\end{tabular} \arrow{ur}   
    &   & C \arrow [shift left=.5ex]{ul} \\
  & D \arrow{ur} & 
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
    &  B \arrow[degil,shift left=1.5ex]{dr}{}  &  \\
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Stochastic\\ Independence\end{tabular}} \arrow{ur}   
    &   & C \arrow [shift left=.5ex]{ul} \\
  & D \arrow{ur} & 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic Enrico! Very nice. Grazie